# How to access properties inside multiple model

Tags: c#

When joining multiple models, I can't access its properties in controller.

```
public class BirdModel
{
    public IEnumerable<BirdFile> BirdFils { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BirdFileDetail> BirdFileDetails { get; set; }
}

public partial class BirdFile
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to access like this

```
BirdModel b = new BirdModel();
b.BirdFile.ID
```

Comment: _Is it possible to access like this?.._ What is stopping you from trying that and seeing if it works or not?

Comment: BirdModel has a property BirdFils, which is a collection of BirdLife-objects. You should take a beginners course of object oriented programming and arrays/lists.

Comment: In `BirdModel` class the property is `BirdFil*s*`. So, the correct access is `b.BirdFil*s*.First().ID`.

Answer (score 1):

You problem with `b.BirdFile.ID` is that you are trying to access the property or a collection of objects that you have not initialised.

You need to create an instance of the encapsulating class, `BirdModel` then create an instance of your `BirdFile` collection and add values to it. From there you can get the specific "BirdFile" within your collection via iteration and then access its properties.

A small example below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var bm = new BirdModel();
        bm.BirdFils = new List<BirdFile>
        {
            new BirdFile {ID = 1, Name = "Bird A"},
            new BirdFile {ID = 2, Name = "Bird B"}
        };
        bm.BirdFils.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Name: {x.Name}, ID: {x.ID}"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public class BirdModel
{
    public IEnumerable<BirdFile> BirdFils { get; set; }

}
public partial class BirdFile
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`BirdModel` contains a collection of `BirdFile`, so to access them you should write something like:

```
// create a new model 
BirdModel b = new BirtdModel()
// create the instance of BirdFile list
b.BirdFils = new List<BirdFile>()
// add an item (just an example)
b.BirdFils.Add(new BirdFile{ ID = 1, Name = "Bird1"}


// Access to the previously created BirdFile
BirdFile bf = b.BirdFils[0]
```